# Shifting values in 2d array

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I am working on a method that stores all the highest values in a given column in a 2d array at the bottom of the column, I use Random class to get different values.

I am stuck there and don't really know what to do now, any help would be much appreciated,

My code so far

```
 void StoreHighestValueAtBottom(int[,] matrix, int column)
    {
        int max = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            if (matrix[row, column] > max)
            {
                max = matrix[row, column];
                Array.Copy(matrix, 0, matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) + 1, matrix.GetLength(0) * matrix.GetLength(1) - matrix.GetLength(0) - 1);
                Array.Copy(new int[matrix.GetLength(0) + 1, 1], max, matrix, max, matrix.GetLength(0) + 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "stores all the highest values in a given column" - are you going to find out a *single* `max` value and put it at the bottom row (swap with the bottom item)?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what are going to implement:

> a method that stores all the highest values in a given column in a 2d array at the bottom of the column

If you want to find out (single) `max` value in the given `column` and *swap* this `max` with the *bottom* item in the column in order
`max` value to be the last in the column:

```
 void StoreHighestValueAtBottom(int[,] matrix, int column) {
   int maxRow = 0;
   int max = matrix[0, column];

   // Find max value and the row where it is
   for (int row = 1; row < matrix.GetLength(0); ++row) {
     if (matrix[row, column] > max) {
       max = matrix[row, column];
       maxRow = row; 
     } 
   }
   
   // swap bottom item and max item 
   int bottom = matrix[matrix.GetLength(0) - 1, column];
   matrix[matrix.GetLength(0) - 1, column] = max;
   matrix[maxRow, column] = bottom; 
 }
```